# Recovering multiple files

Tags: recover

After a crash, I can `recover-this-file`, but, if I don't know which of many files may have been unsaved at the time of the crash, how can I find out?  Can I recover them all in one go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Recover.html)

> If Emacs or the computer crashes, you can recover all the files you
>   were editing from their auto save files with the command `M-x
>   recover-session`. This first shows you a list of recorded interrupted
>   sessions. Move point to the one you choose, and type `C-c C-c`.
>
> Then recover-session asks about each of the files that were being
>   edited during that session, asking whether to recover that file. If
>   you answer y, it calls `recover-file`, which works in its normal
>   fashion. It shows the dates of the original file and its auto-save
>   file, and asks once again whether to recover that file.